# Sending variables to VBA

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

Can I send values to a vba macro when calling it from python?

Python code:

```
def run_access_macro(database_path, macro_name):
    acNormal = 0
    try:
        try:
            access_app = win32com.client.GetObject(Class="Access.Application")
            print("Using existing Access instance.")
        except:
            access_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
            access_app.Visible = True  # Set to False for handoff

        time.sleep(2)

        # Try to get the database if it's already open
        db = None
        try:
            db = access_app.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
            if db:
                print("Using the existing database.")
        except Exception:
            pass

        if db is None:
            # Open the Access database if not already open
            print("opening database")
            db = access_app.OpenCurrentDatabase(database_path)

        # Run the specified macro
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Trying macro: " + macro_name)
        access_app.DoCmd.RunMacro(macro_name) # would like to be able to add "text_parameter" here
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```

I've tried

```
# Run the specified macro with the parameter
access_app.DoCmd.SetParameter("Param1", parameter)
access_app.DoCmd.RunMacro(macro_name)
```

and

```
access_app.DoCmd.SetTempVar("YourParameterName", parameter)
```

but I need to just pass values straight into the code.

Currently I get the message:

An error occurred: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352562), None)

Comment: Have you considered using `Application.Run` instead?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.run

Comment: yes,  the function would just need a `return` statement...

Comment: Why use macro and not VBA? I have tried calling macro with argument from VBScript and doesn't seem to work. However, I can pass argument to VBA procedure. `Application.Run` is to call VBA procedure.

Comment: If you just want to run a macro, you can consider using `run` and the `/X macroname` command-line switch to specify which macro to run and `/cmd args` to pass arguments. This code will behave substantially different when an Access instance is open, yours will try to pass the args and run the macro on any database that may be open, while this approach will open the specified database.

Comment: @ErikA Can you please elaborate of using command line switch in my python script?